# Finding the stationary distribution of a random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

> Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected finite graph and let $\deg(i)$ be the degree of a vertex $i$. Let the transition matrix $P$ of the random walk be given by 
>   $$
> P(i,j) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{\text{deg}(i)}, & (i,j) \in E \\
> 0,                       & (i,j) \notin E
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   and let the walk be reversible wrt some stationary distribution. Find a stationary distribution.

If $\pi$ is a stationary distribution $\pi(i)\times \frac{1}{\text{deg}(i)} = \pi(j)\times \frac{1}{\text{deg}(j)}$ since we have have reversibility. May I know which $\pi$ would satisfy this?

Comment: Is $\pi(i)/\deg(i) $ is constant on connected components of $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the graph is connected: Since $\pi(i) / \deg(i)$ is constant, you're looking for $\pi$ to be proportional to $\deg(i)$ and to have the property that $\sum_x \pi(x) = 1$. These two properties completely specify $\pi$.

To be a bit more explicit: consider $m(i) = \deg(i)$; this is a stationary *measure*. Then, the stationary *distribution* is $\pi(i) = m(i) / \sum_x \pi(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Its not given that the graph is connected. May I know why $\pi(i)/\text{deg}(i)$ would be a constant on a connected graph so that I can say $\pi(i)/\text{deg}(i)$ is constant on a connected component maybe?

Comment: It comes from the equation you wrote, which applies for any neighboring vertices; applying it again to neighbors of neighbors and so forth shows the fraction $\pi(i) / \deg(i) $ to be constant on the whole connected component. And notably, if the graph is disconnected, then there is no unique stationary distribution, but rather multiple stationary distributions that will all apparently work.